# regarding the error message of RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, scipy

In a program, there is one line of code that aims to conduct some transformation or scaling over the image array, i.e., `img`

```
img = img/np.amax(img)
```

However, running the program gives the following error message

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

What can be the cause for this kind of error and how to solve it?

Comment: maybe you should use **img = img/np.nanmax(img)**

Comment: May I know what are the differences between these two usages?

Comment: It still gives the same error message.

Comment: hard to tell without knowing the **img**.  Can you provide  a  code sample with sample img that will generate this error ?